# Detect Database Content Changes in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I need one sql query which can tell the name of DATABASES in which CONTENT or SCHEMA have been changed during last 7 or 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

[Change Data Capture (MSDN bb522489)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) should help.

Answer (score -1):

Please check SQL book online or search on google.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155072.aspx

Comment: `Servers and Enterprise Development` - how is this even remotely connected to what the OP is asking about??